CVXOPT fails to solve LP with CVXPY
I am trying to solve a very simple LP with cvxpy and cvxopt. Here is the code for the model:
import cvxpy as cp
import numpy as np

n = 2
x = cp.Variable(n)

prob = cp.Problem(cp.Maximize(cp.sum(x)), [cp.sum(x) <= 10])
prob.solve(solver=cp.CVXOPT, verbose=True)

print("\nThe optimal value is", prob.value)
print("A solution x is")
print(x.value)
print("A dual solution is")
print(prob.constraints[0].dual_value)

Running this model yields this output:
===============================================================================
                                     CVXPY                                     
                                     v1.4.3                                    
===============================================================================
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Your problem has 2 variables, 1 constraints, and 0 parameters.
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: It is compliant with the following grammars: DCP, DQCP
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: (If you need to solve this problem multiple times, but with different data, consider using parameters.)
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: CVXPY will first compile your problem; then, it will invoke a numerical solver to obtain a solution.
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Your problem is compiled with the CPP canonicalization backend.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  Compilation                                  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Compiling problem (target solver=CVXOPT).
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Reduction chain: FlipObjective -> Dcp2Cone -> CvxAttr2Constr -> ConeMatrixStuffing -> CVXOPT
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Applying reduction FlipObjective
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Applying reduction Dcp2Cone
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Applying reduction CvxAttr2Constr
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Applying reduction ConeMatrixStuffing
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Applying reduction CVXOPT
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Finished problem compilation (took 2.427e-03 seconds).
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                Numerical solver                               
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
(CVXPY) Apr 17 08:41:27 PM: Invoking solver CVXOPT  to obtain a solution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/test2.py", line 8, in <module>
    prob.solve(solver=cp.CVXOPT, verbose=True)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 503, in solve
    return solve_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 1086, in _solve
    self.unpack_results(solution, solving_chain, inverse_data)
  File "/home/me/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cvxpy/problems/problem.py", line 1411, in unpack_results
    raise error.SolverError(
cvxpy.error.SolverError: Solver 'CVXOPT' failed. Try another solver, or solve with verbose=True for more information.


If I change the solver to the default ECOS, the correct solution is returned. Why is the CVXOPT solver unable to solve this problem?
I have tried reinstalling the packages and reading the documentation, but to no avail.

It's a rather peculiar test case so maybe you've hit some corner case where cvxopt is broken or the cvxpy interface to cvxopt is broken. You would have to check carefully and file a bug report in the respective project.
